# How do I create a module that utilizes a custom DB table?

Tags: admin, module, extensions

I am interested in extending the functionality of a site with a few custom modules (e.g. custom registration form - not a newsletter). I know how I would create these tables in MySQL and then reference them in PHP but I would like to keep things cohesive and use the Mage method of pulling and viewing that data correctly with the intended purpose of viewing these registrations in the admin section. I've found one tutorial that goes through the process using the "Module Creator" on Magento's site but I was hoping for something a bit more organic that doesn't involve using his tool.

Reference: http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/0_-_module_development_in_magento/custom_module_with_custom_database_table

Thank you.

Comment: I suggest looking at one of the third-party extensions that utilizes custom tables you have installed and following that. Mage_modeulName (`Mage_WishList` looks pretty good) also could be a good example. Essentially, you need to create an installation script that creates your custom table, set it up in `config.xml`, setup classes in `Model` (e.g. `Mysql4`) directory so you can interact with the tables, etc.

Comment: How is this question off topic? Where do these questions go if not on this forum? The point of this site is to encourage conversation regarding Magento while solving problems. Amazing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After consulting with two certified devs, they both recommended this free service which breaks down the module creation process and for me, was very informative along the way. Hope it helps someone else.

http://www.silksoftware.com/magento-module-creator/